# Get the min value of a grouped set of results

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
id|    date|      shopid|   price|    region_id
1|    10/12/12|    123|      999|       99
2|    10/12/12|    124|      1099|      99
3|    10/12/12|    125|      899|       99

4|    10/12/12|    459|      989|       100
5|    10/12/12|    457|      979|       100
6|    10/12/12|    456|      939|       100
```

What i want to find is the cheapest price for each region on the 10/12/12

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(price) AS price, region_id
FROM FOO
WHERE date = '10/12/12' /*Should use ISO format for dates. Highly ambiguous*/
GROUP BY region_id
```